# Can two Java methods have same name with different return types?

Tags: java, methods, return-type

Can two Java methods have the **same name** with different **return type**? The return type of the methods are different and they are declared with the same method's name.

Is that allowed?

Comment: if class is same and if and only if both methods having different parameter then only it is possible.

Comment: @Aleadam - does it matter?  The OP is asking for information ... not code.

Comment: @Stephen yes, but very easy to find info that can be found in the first chapters of any book, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: are you trying to say same signature or just the method name?this makes lot  of difference

Comment: @Aleadam - I don't follow your reasoning.  Are you saying that if it is homework the OP needs to look up the answer in a book?  (And not otherwise?)  If not, what is the relevance of your question?

Comment: @Stephen, the question is very poorly worded, it doesn't say if the methods reside in the same class, or same class hierarchy (then they can be private ones)

Comment: The question which is marked as a duplicate for this one is a different one. That question asks WHY you can't have different return types in C++ or Java. This one asks IF this is possible. Strictly speaking these are different questions.

Answer (score 96):

If both methods have same parameter types, but different return type than it is not possible. From [Java Language Specification, Java SE 8 Edition, §8.4.2. Method Signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2):

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.

If both methods has different parameter types (so, they have different signature), then it is possible. It is called overloading.

Comment: +1 for linking to the spec ... and being correct and clear.

Comment: But why would this be useful?

Answer (score 37):

Only, if they accept different parameters. If there are no parameters, then you must have different names.

```
int doSomething(String s);
String doSomething(int); // this is fine


int doSomething(String s);
String doSomething(String s); // this is not
```

Comment: Not only. int doSomething(string) and String dosomething(String) has diffrent return types, so signature in Java Bytecode is also diffrent, so it is allowed. To invoke this method, you must use reflection or bytecode.

Comment: @barwnikk: Sure, but return types don't have anything to do with it - they have different names as well due to the difference in capitalization.

Comment: Diffrence in capitalization is, because my shift key is broken. ;) you can create two methods with the same args and method name, but diffrent return values only. But you will got problems in Eclipse. When you call method, you will got error, so you must use bytecode. ;) A lot of obfuscator using this. Class name can be "if", " do", "for", if you know bytecode.

Answer (score 24):

According the JLS, you cannot however due to a feature/bug in the Java 6/7 compiler (Oracle's JDK, OpenJDK, IBM's JDK) you can have different return types for the same method signature if you use generics.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        Main.<Integer>print();
        Main.<Short>print();
        Main.<Byte>print();
        Main.<Void>print();
    }

    public static <T extends Integer> int print() {
        System.out.println("here - Integer");
        return 0;
    }
    public static <T extends Short> short print() {
        System.out.println("here - Short");
        return 0;
    }
    public static <T extends Byte> byte print() {
        System.out.println("here - Byte");
        return 0;
    }
    public static <T extends Void> void print() {
        System.out.println("here - Void");
    }
}
```

Prints

```
here - Integer
here - Short
here - Byte
here - Void
```

For more details, [read my article here](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2011_02_01_archive.html)

Comment: JLS does allow these 4 methods, even if they have the same return type. Actually return type is not considered at all when discussing overloading(#8.4.2). So it's not a bug, per current language spec, to allow these 4 methods. However javac can't compile them if they have the same return type - that *is* a bug. It's the language spec that's guilty for the bug; they didn't think through the whole generics thing very carefully.

Comment: @irreputable, Agreed about the generics, which is why I thought the delay of closures might be a good thing if it meant the design was well thought out. ;)  Just look at what you have to do to create an array of generics, or the use of double and triple casts, or the fact that even `java.util.ArrayList` doesn't compile without warnings (got to be the most basic of use cases)

Answer (score 9):

No. C++ and Java both disallow overloading on a functions's return type. The reason is that overloading on return-type can be confusing (it can be hard for developers to predict which overload will be called). In fact, there are those who argue that any overloading can be confusing in this respect and recommend against it, but even those who favor overloading seem to agree that this particular form is too confusing.

Comment: In Java (at least) two method can have the same name and different return types **provided** that they also have different argument types; see the JLS section linked by @uthark's answer.

Comment: Right, but that isn't overloading on return-type, that is overloading on parameter-type. And the overload simply happens to have a different return-type (the return-type is totally unrelated to the overload).

Answer (score 7):

You can have two methods with the same arguments and different return types only if one of the methods is inherited and the return types are compatible.

For example:

```
public class A
{
    Object foo() { return null; }
}

public class B
    extends A
{
    String foo() { return null; }
}
```

Comment: True, I just discovered this earlier today. If you call `B.class.getDeclaredMethods()` you will see both of them come up. You can call either version via reflection.

Answer (score 4):

The java documentation states:

> The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you cannot declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 4):

Even if it is an old thread, maybe some is interested.

If it is an option to you to use the *same* method inside the same class and archive different return types, use generics: [Oracle Lesson Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

Simple example for generic value holder class:

```
class GenericValue<T> {
  private T myValue;

  public GenericValue(T myValue) { this.myValue = myValue; }

  public T getVal() { return myValue; }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public class ExampleGenericValue {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericValue<Integer> intVal = new GenericValue<Integer>(10);
    GenericValue<String> strVal = new GenericValue<String>("go on ...");

    System.out.format("I: %d\nS: %s\n", intVal.getVal(), strVal.getVal());
  }
}
```

... will result in the following output:

```
I: 10
S: go on ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Only if their parameter declarations are different from memory.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in the same class with the equal number of parameters with the same types and order, 
then it is not possible for example:

```
int methoda(String a,int b) {
        return b;
}
String methoda(String b,int c) {
        return b;    
}
```

if the number of parameters and their types is same but order is different then it is possible since it results in method overloading. It means if the method signature is same which includes method name with number of parameters and their types and the order they are defined.