# Switch according to input and return dynamic value

Tags: java, oop, generics, generic-programming

In this method I get string as input and according to the string name I need to return value sometimes its string sometime int ,double,int64 ,bool etc
Since its dynamic type i don't know how to define it in the method return type
and how to add to it the value and how to call to this method that the return type is dynamic ,any idea?

```
public static ? SwitchInput(String TypeName) {

       if (TypeName == "java.lang.String" ) {
            Return = "A";
        }
        else if (TypeName == "int" ) {
            Return =  1;
        }
        else if (TypeName == "double") {
            Return = 1.00
        }
```

etc for bool and all the other types

```
    }
```

Comment: Is this just pseudo-code or is it valid in any language? It definitely is not Java (e.g. Java uses `equals` for `String` compares, ...).

Comment: Read [Peter Lawrey answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561436/can-two-java-methods-have-same-name-with-different-return-type).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know what the return type is, you have to find a container where all these types fit in. Obviously, this is Object. You'd have to convert the primitive types to the corresponding object (like int to Integer).

A better approach would be to create a new container class, which holds a generic type <T>. Like

```
public class SwitchDemo {

public static SwitchInputType<?> switchInput(String typeName) {
    if (typeName.equals("java.lang.String")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<String>(new String("A"));
    } else if (typeName.equals("int")) {
        return new SwitchInputType<Integer>(new Integer(312));
    }
    return null;
}

public static class SwitchInputType<T> {
    private T type;

    public SwitchInputType(T type) {
        super();
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(T type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwitchInputType<?> sit1 = SwitchDemo.switchInput("java.lang.String");
    System.out.println(sit1.getType());
    SwitchInputType<?> sit2 = SwitchDemo.switchInput("int");
    System.out.println(sit2.getType());
}
```

}

Comment: Can you give example please for the generic type <T> ?

Comment: Thanks ratlan but how would you call to the switchInput i.e. how would you get the data from it  ? thanks again

Comment: SwitchInputType is just a container. Just get the data it contains. See edit

Answer (score 2):

`Object` will be your best bet, unless returned type shares an Ancestor

Example :

```
public static Object switchInput(String typeName) {       

   if ("java.lang.String".equals(typeName)) {
        return "A";
    }
    else if ("int".equals(typeName)) {
        return 1i;
    }
    else if ("double".equals(typeName)) {
        return 1.0d
    }
 }
```

Another example with generics

```
 static <T> T switchInput(String typeName){
   if ("java.lang.String".equals(typeName)) {
    return "A";
    }
    else if ("int".equals(typeName)) {
        return 1i;
    }
    else if ("double".equals(typeName)) {
        return 1.0d
    }

 }

 String str = MyClass.switchInput("java.lang.String")
```

I have not tested that, this is a simpler version of my first thought about generics

Comment: Can you provide an example for your answer?

Comment: Thank I mean but how you would retrieve the data from the object with value of?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The runtime class of the object returned is the one you want

Comment: Does this way is better (for me of course)than using the generic <T> option ?

Comment: I ask it because at the end I need to ask in the method that call to the switch method if obj instance of ....

Comment: The `<T>` option will require you to know at Compile time the type of returned object. But it's certainly better to have a `static <T> T switchInput(Class<T> type)`

Comment: Can you provide an example for it please?

Answer (score 1):

As an ugly solution to your problem, you could set your method to run the type Object. (as Boolean, Integer, Double are all subtypes)

You would have to ensure though that you then inferred the correct type afterwards when using the returned value (using instanceof) and recast it to the correct type.

Can I ask though why you need such a method? This is abusing the notion of a method definition slightly.

```
  public static Object SwitchInput(String TypeName) {

   if (TypeName.equals("java.lang.String") ) {
        Return = new String("A");
    }
    else if (TypeName.equals("int") ) {
        Return =  new Integer(1);
    }
    else if (TypeName.equals("double")) {
        Return = new Double(1.00) ;
    }
 etc for bool and all the other types

}
```

And using this code snippet to infer what type it is further on down in your code

```
  if(returned_value instanceof Double)
```

etc.

Comment: I need this method creating value to the type that i get for example if i get string i need to return value like string1 string2 etc and if i get int i need to return the value etc according to type name,since you think that this is ugly solution how would you do it different ?