# The return type is incompatible with LinkedList<T>

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, overriding

Eclipse is giving me a return type incompatible error on an inherited method that I've overridden.

I have a generic SomeQueue class that extends LinkedList and implements a generic this is my generic SomeList class

```
public abstract class SomeQueue<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements SomeList<T>{
private int capacity=100;
public SomeQueue(){
 super();
Queue<E> tqueue=new LinkedList<T>();
T front=null;
T back=null;}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty(){}

@Override
public E get(int index){}

@Override
public int size(){}

@Override
public void add(T thing){}

@Override
public E removeEnd(){}

@Override
public void addFirst(T thing){}

@Override
public T remove(int index){}
}
```

and here's my SomeList interface

```
public interface SomeList<T>{
public boolean isEmpty();
public T get(int index);
public int size();
public void add(T item);
public T removeEnd();
public void addFirst(T thing);
public T remove(int index);}
```

Eclipse gives me an error on the `add(T thing)` method in the `QueueLis<T>` class. 
that explicitly says that

> The return type is incompatible with `LinkedList<T>.add(T)`

and suggests to change the return type to boolean which I don't want to do. The `@Override` above the `add(T thing)` method in SomeQueue doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You should always post the relevant parts of your stack trace.

Comment: My bad, I just kind of glossed over when I never saw the stack trace. Been too many questions lately that could have easily been answered otherwise!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This error is appearing because the extending/implementing class has two methods with the same name and argument types (signature), and different return types. In this case the compiler is complaining specifically about the `add(T)` method.

Your `LinkedStack` class is probably extending `LinkedList`, and therefore its `boolean add(T)` method. The `void add(T)` method inherited from `SomeList` and overriden in `SomeQueue` is incompatible with the one in `LinkedList`, because they have different return types (and the same name and arguments).

Putting it shortly, When you called `SomeQueue.add(T)`, the compiler wouldn't know if you want to call the method that returns a `boolean` or the one that returns an `int`.

In other words, when you define `void add(T t)`, the `@Override` doesn't match `LinkedList.add(T)` (which returns a  `boolean`), and if you made it return a `boolean` the `@Override` wouldn't match `SomeList.add(T)`, which must return `void`.

As a side note, by just having a class implement `SomeList` and extend `LinkedList`, without defining an `add` method:

```
public abstract class SomeQueue<T> 
                extends LinkedStack<T> 
                implements SomeList<T>{ /* Empty class definition */ }
```

, the compiler should already give an error along the lines of the following

> The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods LinkedStack.add(E), LinkedList.add(E)

You should really consider if you need that `add` method as is in the `SomeList` interface (you could also change its name), and if you really need it to be as is now, then detach your class from the whole [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)) hierarchy.

Related question: [Can two Java methods have same name with different return types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5561436/851811)