# Spring Boot Kotlin Jersey ModelValidationException

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, kotlin

I am trying to get Spring Boot + Jersey working with Kotlin. I configured the way I typically would in Java but getting a the following stacktrace. It seems to indicate the controller is being instantiated twice but it shouldn't.

Here is my JerseyConfig class:

```
package com.joescodeshack.igdb.config

import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.KotlinModule
import com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller.GenreController
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath

@Component
@ApplicationPath("/api")
open class JerseyConfig : ResourceConfig {

    constructor() {
        register(GenreController());
    }

    @Bean
    open fun objectMapperBuilder(): Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
            = Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder().modulesToInstall(KotlinModule())
}
```

GenreController (JAX-RS endpoint)

```
package com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller

import com.joescodeshack.igdb.domain.Genre
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

@Path("/genre")
open class GenreController {

    val genres : List<Genre> = listOf(Genre(1,"Butt"), Genre(2, "Cow"))

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    open fun getGenres() : Response {
        return Response.ok(genres).build();
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
2016-09-06 15:26:26.529 ERROR 17332 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[.j.i.c.JerseyConfig]    : Allocate exception for servlet com.joescodeshack.igdb.config.JerseyConfig

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] A resource model has ambiguous (sub-)resource method for HTTP method GET and input mime-types as defined by"@Consumes" and "@Produces" annotations at Java methods public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller.GenreController.getGenres() and public final java.util.List com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller.GenreController.getGenres() at matching regular expression /genre. These two methods produces and consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as a resource methods will always fail.; source='org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.RuntimeResource@1b6cce78']
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:555) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255) ~[jersey-common-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:347) ~[jersey-server-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:392) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.23.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1194) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:806) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:133) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the following property:

```
val genres : List<Genre> = listOf(Genre(1,"Butt"), Genre(2, "Cow"))
```

Generates a method that on JVM level has a following signature:

```
@NotNull
public final List<Genre> getGenres()
```

As you can see it conflicts with the other method in your controller. To resolve it change the property to be `private` or rename one of the methods.

PS. The error message is pretty clear about the problem:

> `public javax.ws.rs.core.Response
>   com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller.GenreController.getGenres()` and
>   `public final java.util.List
>   com.joescodeshack.igdb.controller.GenreController.getGenres()` at
>   matching regular expression /genre. These two methods produces and
>   consumes exactly the same mime-types and therefore their invocation as
>   a resource methods will always fail.;

Comment: @voddan [JVM allows this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36701687/155213) and from Kotlin perspective the getter and method are distinguishable. I wonder though if this should be an error since it's forbidden in Java.

Comment: Thank you for the link, strange indeed. I was sure it were a "clashing jvm signature error" in kotlinc